# sed to change dns log string format

Tags: sed, regular-expression, dns, replace

I want to use sed to change the following text:

```
(3)www(5)first(3)nth(6)domain(3)com(0)
```

to:

```
www.first.nth.domain.com
```

Can each group between the parenthesis separators be captured and then reconstructed in order with period separators assuming that there will be from 2 to n+3 groups (infinity)?  Is there another way?

I am already familiar with:

```
s/\(\d+\)/./g
```

but that only yields:

```
.www.first.nth.domain.com.
```

Comment: For the purposes of the RE is the number in brackets relevant?

Comment: Nothing stopping you from removing the first and last dot.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to satisfy your requirement. I'm not entirely sure whether you are looking to use the numbers in the brackets to validate the run-lengths, but I'm assuming not.

```
echo '(3)www(5)first(3)nth(6)domain(3)com(0)' |
sed -r -e 's/^\([0-9]+\)//' -e 's/(.)\([0-9]+\)(.)/\1.\2/g' -e 's/\([0-9]+\)$//'
www.first.nth.domain.com
```

The `sed` uses three different REs. The first and last strip off the bounded leading and trailing `(\d+)` expressions. The middle one strips the remainder.

Comment: basically three passes of sed?  Is there no way to do it in just one pass?  There is a reason for needing just one pass (sedcmd).

Comment: @landen99 one pass with three operations. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

How about `s/\([0-9]+\)/./g; s/^\.|\.$//g`?

Your `\d` construction won't be recognized by some sed implementations.  The above is a Posix extended regular expression.  Which, you know, *should* work.

The trick in `sed` is just to work incrementally.  You got most of the way there by replacing the parenthesized digits; you just didn't realize you could clean up the result with a second regex.

Comment: The thing is that extended regex is not (yet) supported by POSIX `sed`. You'll have to use BRE for full portability.